# Rotation of a coordinate system.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, coordinate-systems, rotations

I have this reallife situation:

- a camera
- a 3d workingplane with its own coordinate system.

The 3D working plane is described via a "Pose". This pose contains the X,Y,Z shift and the X,Y,Z rotation along the axis, relative to the camera. So basically, you can imagine the center of the camera being the absolute zero, with the Z axis going through the lense Y going up, and X going right.

Then there is this second coordinate system that is the 0 of my working plane. The pose describes the position of this second coordinate system relative to the camera coordinate system.

Now, I would need to edit the pose in a way, that it rotates the working plane on a specific axis for a specific angle, but cant figure out how to do this mathematically. The workingplane can have any position relative to the camera.

how can I calculate, for example, how a 90° rotation around the X axis of the working plane affects the 3 angles the pose?

A sample pose in Meters and Degrees:

Shift X: 0.198406

Shift Y: 0.169682

Shift Z: 0.458127

Rotation Along X Axis: 37.2069

Rotation Along Y Axis: 0.1987

Rotation Along Z Axis: 180.114

**to clarify:**

the camera does not rotate. it is stationary. I rotate the working plane 90 degrees about the x axis, and need to update the pose that describes the position of the workingplane relative to the camera. Given that the two coordinate systems (camera and workingplane) are not parallel, any rotation on any axis will have an effect on all 3 axes of the pose describing the position of the working plane.

Comment: From my understanding, if you rotate about the x-axis 90 degrees, then the camera will rotate forwards or backwards 90 degrees so that the lens will be facing directly downwards or upwards if rotated from a 0 shift in X. Is this what you're describing?

Comment: @CoyCatrett nope, the camera does not rotate. it is stationary. I rotate the working plane 90 degrees about the x axis, and need to update the pose that describes the position of the workingplane relative to the camera. Given that the two coordinate systems (camera and workingplane) are not parallel, any rotation on any axis will have an effect on all 3 axes of the pose describing the position of the working plane.

Comment: You should put some linear algebra/ transformation tags under this post as well. Sorry I'm not able to help. good luck